# Unable to run python program on mininet. No Errors

Tags: python, sdn, mininet

I am new to python and currently following Nick Feamster class of SDN. I was able to run basic python programs till today, but then I started getting issues wherein when I run the program by using the command "sudo python custom.py" I don't get any output.

```
mininet@SDN-VirtualBox:~/mininet/custom$ sudo python custom.py

mininet@SDN-VirtualBox:~/mininet/custom$
```

While troubleshooting I also tried to clear the controller using command `sudo fuser -k 6633/tcp` and mininet `sudo mn -c`

I have also tried to restart my Virtual box but that is no help.

I don't think the issue is related to my program as I have tried running others and have got the same results. Still pasting my code.

---

My Program:

```
from mininet.topo import Topo
from mininet.net import Mininet
from mininet.util import dumpNodeConnections
from mininet.log import setLogLevel

class SingleSwitchTopo(Topo):
        "Single switch connected to n hosts."

        def build(self, n=2):
                switch = self.addSwitch('S1')
                for h in range(n):
                        host = self.addHost('h%s' % (h+1))
                        self.addLink(host, switch)

def simpleTest():
        "Create and test a simple network"
        topo = SingleSwitchTopo(n=4)
        net = Mininet(topo)
        net.start()
        print "Dumping host connections"
        dumpNodeConnections(net.hosts)
        print "Testing network connectivity"
        net.pingAll()
        net.stop

if __name__ == '__main__':
        setLogLevel('info')
        simpleTest()
```

Comment: Hello Vivek to SO. Basically you need to run your definitions. You defined one class (`SingleSwitchTopo`) and one function (`simpleTest`) but you don't call it anywhere. Something like `simpleTest()` and the end of the file should help.

Comment: I made some correction to the above code as what you mentioned and now I am getting below error:

File "custom.py", line 28, in <module>
    simpleTest()
  File "custom.py", line 17, in simpleTest
    topo = SingleSwitchTopo(n=2)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'n'

Comment: It seems that `Topo` doesn't accept keyword arguments.

Comment: I got the solution, pasting it here for newbies like me. I am using Mininet version 2.1 which recommends a preferred method to override was __init__ rather than build()

class SingleSwitchTopo(Topo):
    "Single switch connected to n hosts."
    def __init__(self, n=2, **opts):
        # Initialize topology and default options
        Topo.__init__(self, **opts)
        switch = self.addSwitch('s1')
        # Python's range(N) generates 0..N-1
        for h in range(n):
            host = self.addHost('h%s' % (h + 1))
            self.addLink(host, switch)